# Printing a partial input file

Tags: python

I have to use Python 2.5.2 to solve a problem for work.  I'm very new to Python and greatly apreciate this resource.

I need to print part of an input file starting from a position in a line, on through all remaining lines until the /eof is reached.  The resulting data will have to be written to another file.

My biggest concern is reading the partial file.  In my research, which I confess has been less than a day, I have not seen any references on how to read a partial input file.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.  It may be that the form of my query may be the problem, so even a suggestion in that area would be welcome.

Comment: Please include sample input and expected output as well.

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` reads the file and stores each line in a list. Since you want to start at an index and print everything from that index till the very end, `readlines()` seems the method of choice. For example:

```
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()  # read everything in the file and store it in a list
begin_at = 5  # just an example.
for i in range( begin_at, len(lines) ):
    print lines[i]
```

If memory is a concern, and if you only want parts of the file in the buffer, then that will require additional work. Check out [this blog post](http://www.nikhilgopal.com/2010/12/dealing-with-large-files-in-python.html) (specifically, "Method 3").

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load the whole file and only the part needed, here is a workaround:

```
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
start = 10 #start from the 10th line
for i in range(start):
   f.next()
content = file.read()
```